# SAAJ: XML in TextNode. Quotes not Escaped

Tags: java, xml, soap, saaj

together
I ty to build a SOAP Request with SAAJ. All works fine but now I have to send an other XMl Document inside the SOAP Body inside SOAP Element.

I tried follwing code:

```
SOAPElement file = service.addChildElement(new QName("nameOfTextNode"));
file.addTextNode(xmlString);
```

The Problem is most characters are correctly escaped (e.g. '<' -> `&lt;`) but not single or double quotes. I can't use CDATA or let the quotes as they are, because i don't have control over the SOAP Service and they can't support CDATA or want to change anything.

When I use anothe Library to escape the String first. It will be escaped twice in the SOAP Request.

Do aynone have an idea? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SAAJ doesn't escape single or double quotes in this case because it's not required. If the service requires that, then it doesn't conform to the XML specification and therefore isn't a SOAP service. Since SAAJ implements SOAP, you won't be able to use it.